# Unexpected behaviour from console log output with Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

I decided to make the transition from the Realtime database to Firestore however I'm running into some unexpected issues. It's very simple: the browser console logs out extremely unexpected results but the methods like exist still work as expected.

```js
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/firestore');

const firebaseConfig = {
   the usual
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

(async () => {
    const userRef = firestore.doc('users/fjafSAe2VQRWx7g9ocxn')
    const snapShot = await userRef.get();
    console.log(snapShot)
    console.log(snapShot.exists)
})()
```

Now the console.log puts out some jibberish in the browser that I cannot understand:

```js
t {pf: e, w_: t, Nf: n, Ff: false, $f: false, …}
$f: false
Ff: false
Nf: n {key: t, version: t, nn: t, Ye: false, hasCommittedMutations: false}
m_: null
pf: e {cf: n, uf: e, hf: FirebaseAppImpl, lf: e, INTERNAL: {…}, …}
w_: t {path: n}
exists: (...)
id: (...)
metadata: (...)
ref: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

However the snapShot.exists works as expected. Even stranger is that when I console log the above in Node.js it outputs the DocumentSnapshot

```js
DocumentSnapshot {
  _firestore:
   Firestore {
     _offlineComponentProvider:
      MultiTabOfflineComponentProvider { onlineComponentProvider: OnlineComponentProvider {} },
     _onlineComponentProvider: OnlineComponentProvider {},
     _firebaseApp:
      FirebaseAppImpl {
        firebase_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '[DEFAULT]',
        automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false,
        options_: [Object],
        container: [ComponentContainer] },
     _queue:
      AsyncQueue {
        tail: [Promise],
        retryableOps: [],
        _isShuttingDown: false,
        delayedOperations: [Array],
        failure: null,
        operationInProgress: true,
        timerIdsToSkip: [],
        backoff: [ExponentialBackoff],
        visibilityHandler: [Function] },
     INTERNAL: { delete: [Function: delete] },
     _databaseId:
      DatabaseId { projectId: 'ecommerce-33931', database: '(default)' },
     _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
     _credentials:
      FirebaseCredentialsProvider {
        tokenListener: [Function],
        currentUser: [User],
        receivedInitialUser: true,
        tokenCounter: 1,
        changeListener: [Function],
        forceRefresh: false,
        auth: null },
     _settings:
      FirestoreSettings {
        host: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
        ssl: true,
        credentials: undefined,
        timestampsInSnapshots: true,
        ignoreUndefinedProperties: false,
        cacheSizeBytes: 41943040,
        experimentalForceLongPolling: false },
     _firestoreClient:
      FirestoreClient {
        credentials: [FirebaseCredentialsProvider],
        asyncQueue: [AsyncQueue],
        clientId: 'exM4ONFeK4q2tpdTjiyl',
        initializationDone: [Deferred],
        databaseInfo: [DatabaseInfo],
        persistence: [MemoryPersistence],
        sharedClientState: [MemorySharedClientState],
        localStore: [LocalStoreImpl],
        gcScheduler: null,
        datastore: [DatastoreImpl],
        remoteStore: [RemoteStoreImpl],
        syncEngine: [SyncEngineImpl],
        eventMgr: [EventManagerImpl] } },
  _key:
   DocumentKey { path: ResourcePath { segments: [Array], offset: 0, len: 2 } },
  _document:
   Document {
     key: DocumentKey { path: [ResourcePath] },
     version: SnapshotVersion { timestamp: [Timestamp] },
     objectValue: ObjectValue { proto: [Object] },
     hasLocalMutations: false,
     hasCommittedMutations: false },
  _fromCache: false,
  _hasPendingWrites: false,
  _converter: null }
```

However the exists property is not listed here (but is still logged as true). Any idea what's causing this? I'm working in React and when it didn't work also tried it in Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default stringified representation of a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) type object.  It doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to examine its contents this way, because it's an internally complex object that itself contains many references to other objects that are also being stringified here.  If you want to see the document data inside that snapshot, you should simply call [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) on it to get a simple JavaScript object that will log easily.

```
console.log(snapShot.data())
```

Comment: Okay thanks! The course I'm following still showed it in the console log but I guess it has changed. Thanks for the tip I will surely use the data method in the future. Cheers